# Javascript regexp pattern with fixed length, leading spaces and digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression pattern that matches a fixed length string (six characters) of digits with leading spaces. The spaces (zero or max 5) are always at left side of the string. The digits (1 or max 6) are always at right side.
So:

```
"     4" is valid
"123456" is valid too

"12    " is not valid
"  12  " is not valid
"12  34" is not valid
"      " is not valid
```

I tried with `/^( ){0,5}(\d){1,6}$/` but it doesn't work because it doesn't check the overall length of the string. I tried also `/^( |\d){6}$/` but it doesn't check the position of spaces/digits. Now I'm stuck, I know there's a solution but I can't find by myself nor by searching the internet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert a length of 6 characters:

```
^(?=.{6}$)[ ]{0,5}[0-9]{1,6}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=.{6}$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is 6 characters and assert the end of the string.
- `[ ]{0,5}[0-9]{1,6}` Match a space 0-5 times, match a digit 1-6 times
- `$` End of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOOM7E/1)

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem. Could you clarificate the need of two $ (dollar sign)? It seems redundant to me, especially the first one. Thanks.

Comment: @Mzm In the first part `^(?=.{6}$)` you assert that right after the start there must be exactly 6 characters followed by the end of the string. If you would leave out the `$` there then matching 5 times a space followed by 6 times a digit would also match.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
^(?:\d{6}|\s\d{5}|\s{2}\d{4}|\s{3}\d{3}|\s{4}\d{2}|\s{5}\d{1})$
```

or for JUST spaces

```
^(?:\d{6}| \d{5}| {2}\d{4}| {3}\d{3}| {4}\d{2}| {5}\d{1})$
```

There may be a more elegant way to do it but it checks for all of the combinations of whitespace and digits.